# How to add a variable from input field to the mail subject?

Tags: php, email, variables, phpmailer

Im using contact form tool to send email from input form data.

The tool automatically sets up subject with text and the data from input field 'name'. I want to add data from input 'code' to the subject.

Function where the subject is set up:

```
 function SendFormSubmission()
{
    $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $this->mailer->Subject = "$code $this->code $this->name";

    $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

    $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

    $this->mailer->AddSubject= $this->code;

    $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

    $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

    $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
    $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

    $this->AttachFiles();

    if(!$this->mailer->Send())
    {
        $this->add_error("Failed sending email!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It doesn't add data from code input.

**whole project:**
https://ide.c9.io/rokas_m/contactform_php

Comment: Please show more code. Where you set `$code` and `$this->code`?

Comment: whole project is here: https://ide.c9.io/rokas_m/contactform_php

i set it up likethis:

funnction GetCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

Comment: It's need login and registration.

Comment: can you show me how i should set $code?

i have <input name="code" type="text">

Comment: you may want to start by finding out if $code, or $this -> code have any content. Try a simple `print $code` and see if anything is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to function: `function CollectData(){}`
2. Write into this function in new line:
   `$this->code = $this->Sanitize($_POST['code']);`
3. Go to `$this->mailer->Subject = "$code $this->code $this->name";` and remove `"$code"`.

It's better to show all your code, even it's copy/paste from internet. It'll help us.